# Is there a word for the piece of clothing worn on the head by a bride?

Tags: word-request

[image]

I am wondering if there's a word for it.

Comment: If it can be pulled forward to cover her face it is a veil.

Comment: 'Head-dress' or 'headdress' can be used for bridal headwear with or without veils.